# Blank page with Vue.js and Ionic side menu

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, ionic-framework

I'm using Vue.js with Ionic, and I'm very confused about good practices with the site menu.  (I'm using typescript too.)

I got a blank page with a warning

> **ion-split-pane-ios.entry.js?f0b4:45 [DEPRECATED][ion-split-pane] Using the [main] attribute is deprecated, please use the "contentId" property instead**

I hope you can help me.

App.vue :

```
<template>
    <ion-app>
      <ion-split-pane>
        <Menu/>
        <ion-vue-router main :animated="false" id="menu-content" />
      </ion-split-pane>
    </ion-app>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";
import Menu from "./components/Menu.vue";

@Component({
  components: {
    Menu
  }
})

export default class App extends Vue {}
</script>
```

Menu.vue :

```
<template>
  <ion-menu contentId="menu-content">
    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar color="primary">
        <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item>Menu Item</ion-item>
        <ion-item>Menu Item</ion-item>
        <ion-item>Menu Item</ion-item>
        <ion-item>Menu Item</ion-item>
        <ion-item>Menu Item</ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-menu>
</template>



<script lang="ts">
  import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
  export default class Menu extends Vue {}
</script>
```

Home.vue :

```
<template>
  <div class="ion-page">
    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar color="primary">
        <ion-buttons slot="start">
          <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
        </ion-buttons>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";
export default class Home extends Vue {}
</script>
```

In my mind, this is the right way but I don't know.. aha 
Thanks

Comment: Have you tested without the [main] attribute?

Comment: @David.J yes like `      <ion-split-pane contentId="menu-content"> ` but the warning message is still there..